# Save post data from a form with listview

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

i have a listview of form:

```
class MatchsView(ListView):
    model = Match2x1
    template_name = 'matchs.html'
```

and the template render this:

```
{% for match in object_list %}
    <form action="/apostar/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <p><input type="radio" name="{{match.id}}" value="{{match.team_a}}">{{match.team_a}}</input></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Apostar"></input>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

as you can see each form has two fields, i need to save in DB the values that the user choose, with FormView its easy, but since this time is a ListView im a little bit lose to save in DB from a form, i know that i have to create a view that handles the form, but really i dont know how to create the view that handles the post data of each form. For example lets says that i need to save the post data in a model called `FormsMatchs`, how can i do it?

i was trying with this:

```
class FormView(FormView):
    form_class = FormMatch
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = 'matchs.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        hola = Country.objects.create(name=request.POST)
```

but is saving this:

```
<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'tCIQuGlSXKJL0R5eo9R5w09ldeBt7zNW'], u'5': [u'River']}>
```

Comment: Can you please add your form here?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet if you want to have a simple list of a given model but also accept a Form is to use a FormView, and override `get_context_data(self, **kwargs)` to pass a queryset into the context, like so:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(MatchsView, self).get_context_data()
    context['object_list'] = Match2x1.objects.all()
    return context
```

However, you can also use a FormMixin with a ListView, see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406553/django-class-based-view-listview-with-form).

Comment: thanks, but is there some way to do it without an override, because the thing is i need only some fields of the form and besides i need to put other field where user fill an info, i forgot to put it but the form has other field and this fields has not come from the model